# Firefox/Chrome unable to connect to sites on VMWare Guest

Tags: google-chrome, security, firefox, certificate, vmware-workstation

I'm seeing this problem connecting to most sites when connected to our office LAN.

I'm running a VM (using VMWare Workstation 15 Player) running Win10. The host is also Win10.

```
    Your connection is not secure

The owner of www.google.com has configured their web site improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this web site.

This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.
```

Advanced shows

```
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

The network connection is "NAT: Used to share the host's IP address".
I had Avast installed and uninstalled it so ensure it was not blocking the connections.

I do not get this error on the host machine

If I connect the host machine to our corporate VPN or use a Wifi connection, I do not get this error.

The date and time are also correct.

Is there something that VMWare Player is doing to the connection?

- Firefox Quantum 65.0.2
- Chrome Version 72.0.3626.121

**Chrome**
[image]

**Firefox**
[image]